# How to create model for other User

Tags: typescript, graphql, nexus, prisma

ive been working on a project and i recently starting on users following other users and seeing there content im using(prisma, graphql, and nexus) so today i created a following model it looks like this

```
model Following {
id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
followId Int
User     User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
userId   Int?
}
```

Ii thought this would work but i realized that it would just return me as the user and not the user i followed so my question is how can i fix this problem would i create another model or just readjust some things on the current one

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, for each user you need the following:

1. Be able to add/remove `User A` to the followers of `User B`
2. Find `User` records that follow a certain user.
3. Find `User` records a certain user is following.

You don't necessarily need to explicitly define a separate model. Instead, you can use a `many-to-many`self-relation for this. Here is what your `User` model would look like in the Prisma Schema

```
model User {
  id        String  @id @default(uuid())  // or whatever your unique id field is. 

  following User[]   @relation("UserFollows", references: [id]) 
  followers User[]   @relation("UserFollows", references: [id])

  // ...other fields in user table
}
```

#### Add/Remove followers for a certain user

If a user record already exists, you can add another user as a follower like this:

```js
const updatedUser = await prisma.user.update({
        where: {
            id: followedUserId,
        },
        data: {
            followers: {
                connect: {   // change to disconect for removing a follower. 
                    id: followerUserId,
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

You can also remove a user from another user's followers by changing the `connect` call to a `disconnect` call.

#### Find a user's followers and following lists.

You can do this to fetch a `user` record along with their follower and following lists.

```js
 const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: userId,
        },
        include: {
            followers: true,   // list of followers for userId
            following: true,   // list of users that follow userId
        },
    });
```

You can learn more about self relations in this [concept guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations) at the Prisma Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/datamodeling/making-connections#introduction and

Seems like you are trying to create a one to many relationship :

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-many-relations